# Let $\{x_n\}$ be a real sequences such that $7x_{n+1}=x_n^3+6$. Find the True statements.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $\{x_n\}$ be a real sequences such that $$7x_{n+1}=x_n^3+6.$$ Then which of the following statements are **TRUE**?

- If $x_1=\frac{1}{2},$ Then $x_n$ coverges to $1$
- If $x_1=\frac{1}{2},$ Then $x_n$ coverges to $2$
- If $x_1=\frac{3}{2},$ Then $x_n$ coverges to $1$
- If $x_1=\frac{3}{2},$ Then $x_n$ coverges to $-3$

**My attempt**
$7x_{n+1}-7x_{n}=x_n^3-x_{n-1}^3=(x_n-x_{n-1})(x_n^2+x_nx_{n-1}+x_{n-1}^2)$

If $x_1=\frac{1}{2}$, $x_2=\frac{\frac{1}{2}^3+6}{7}\geq \frac{1}{2}=x_1,$ Inducting we get, $\{x_n\}$ increasing sequence. and bounded above by 1. The possible limits for the sequences are $1,2,-3$. So, $1$ is the limit. So, option 2 is false. Option $4$ is also false. Since, sequence is inceasing. But the answer is given is option 1 and option 3.

Answer (score 1):

Observe that if $x_1 = \frac{3}{2} $ , you can find $x_2 = 1.3378...< 1.5 = \frac{3}{2} $. And by induction $x_n < \frac{3}{2}$  then the sequence is decreasing and  bounded
below by $1$. So you still get the limit $1$ though. So option 3 remains valid.

Answer (score 1):

[image]
When

$x_1 \le 1$ then $  x_{n+1} > x_n$ and  converge to $1=f(1)$

but

$x_1> 1$ then it diverge